# Why is 76561198272848927 === 76561198272848930 true?

Tags: javascript

I currently try my best with the SteamAPI, for that I need the Profile-IDs. I tried out with my own, but somehow js changes the id.
EG:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOYDt.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZyAT.jpg

My ID is 76561198272848927, but JS somehow always change the last two digits from 27 to 30. Why? And how do I fix this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: You're exceeding the maximum "safe integer" size of an IEEE floating-point number. Your best bet is probably to represent the IDs as strings.

Comment: Consider using BigINTs instead? `76561198272848927n === 76561198272848930n // false`

Comment: These are IDs, not numbers. Don't convert them to numbers, use the strings!